# Error Installing rvm. scripts directory is missing from .rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, nitrousio, koding

I found a few posts regarding installing rvm, but none of them apply here. On a fresh VM installation on Koding, I've followed the instruction to install rvm

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

This seems to work fine, there are no errors downloading the 2 .tar.gz and .tar.gz.asc files

Then when i activate rvm using : 
  source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

that's when i get the error message "bash:  /home/railspadawan/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory".

I checked .rvm and the scripts directory is missing. I experienced the same problem on Nitrous.io, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't working as the gpg signature verification had failed. I downloaded the signatures and voila! it works now.

```
rvm has started enforcing GPG signing and the problem surfaced some 3-4 days back (https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3110). Looks like a necessary step from now for all new rvm installations.
```

1) gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
 This installs GPG signatures. rvm has started enforcing GPG signing and the problem surfaced some 3-4 days back (https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3110).

Steps 2 & 3 are unique to Nitrous.io and are a result of error messages during the rvm install.
2) unset GEM_HOME 
3) added source ~/.profile to .bash_profile

followed by the rvm install steps

1) $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
2) source /home/action/.rvm/scripts/rvm

cheers,
shalini